# Updating rows of a column with list of values in PostgreSQL by psychopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I have a table environment with a column noise, I need to update all rows in the noise column, with a list of values, new_dB_values_list with len(new_dB_values_list) = no. of rows.
My code is this:

```
PsqlCon = psycopg2.connect(host="xx.xxx.xxx.xx", dbname='all_green', user='xxxx' , password='yzzxxx')
con = PsqlCon.cursor()
con.execute("""UPDATE environment SET noise new_dB_values_list;""")
```

What am I doing wrong, what is the correct method. Thanks.

Getting error:

```
ERROR:root:Internal Python error in the inspect module.
Below is the traceback from this internal error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "new_dB_values_list"
LINE 1: UPDATE environment SET noise new_dB_values_list;
                                     ^

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AttributeError: 'ProgrammingError' object has no attribute '_render_traceback_'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
AssertionError
```

Comment: you're doing pretty much everything wrong... your first mistake is probably assuming that SQL tables are ordered.

Comment: easiest fix is to use a loop to update one value at a time.

Comment: Thanks for response, will test that way.

Comment: I think you also need to add an = sign so 'SET noise = new_dB_values_list'